# Multiset to set operator

Tags: co.combinatorics

Is there an operator that transform a Multiset into a set by choosing all the distinct elements? Is there a better/more accurate way to write it than this:

We denote the set $S$ by choosing the distinct elements in the Multiset $A$.  I.e., $S=distinct(A)$

For example assume $A=\{2,3,3,3,5\}$ then $S=distinct(A)=\{2,3,5\}$

Comment: What do you mean by "the distinct elements"? Do you discard the indistinct ones? What is a "super set"?

Comment: yes, a super set is a set that can contain the same alement several times.  For example $A=\{2,3,3,3,5\} $  then $S=distinct(A)=\{1,3,5\}$

Comment: I am not familiar with that use of the expression "superset", nor is wikipedia, nor are any of my books on set theory. Where did you come across this use of the expression "superset"?

Comment: I would prefer to say that what you call a "superset" is a function valued in the natural numbers, and that your "set of distinct elements" is the support of that function. But I would also say that zero is a natural number, and some people would not.

Comment: you right, so is there a name for a set that contains duplicate elements?

Comment: (Technical comment to second @BenMcKay: in combinatorics, this is called a *multiset*, and Ben's proposed formalization is the usual one there, as evidenced by e.g. Stanley's monographs 'Enumerative Combinatorics')

Comment: re " is there a name for a set that contains duplicate elements": yes, the name is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset) says that this operator is the *support* operator, $S=\operatorname{supp} A$.